# Flutter: Child Widget's looses state when parent's sate changes

Tags: flutter, flutter-state

I am learning Flutter and struggling with some state management issue.

I have a HomeScreen widget which contains Scaffold and a BottomNavigationBar. To switch pages based on the selected tab in BottomNavigationBar I am using PageView with PageController. Here is how the `build` method of HomeScreen widget looks:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: _currentIndex == 2,
      appBar: AppBar(...properties),
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        children: _pages,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[...items],
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,  //This changes state _currentIndex and calls the method _pageController.jumpToPage(_currentIndex);
      ),
    );
  }
```

- `_currentIndex` initially is 0.
- `_pages` is a list containing 3 widgets.
- `_pageController` is simple PageController with initialPage set to 0.

If you notice I am using a property `extendBodyBehindAppBar: _currentIndex == 2` which is using `_currentIndex` state and this is causing issue.
When I tap on the last Tab on the BottomNavigationBar the state the `_currentIndex` changes to 2 and thus the `extendBodyBehindAppBar` is set as `true` which makes entire Scaffold rebuild itself and the state of the PageView is lost.

If comment out the line `extendBodyBehindAppBar: _currentIndex == 2`, then even if the Scaffold rebuilds the state of the PageView widget is preserved.

As of my understanding the Flutter should keep the state of child Widgets even if the parent rebuilds because the WidgetTree is not changed or re-arranged. I tried using Key on PageView but nothing worked.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer to [Lucas Salton Cardinali post on medium](https://medium.com/@lucassaltoncardinali/keeping-state-with-the-bottom-navigation-bar-in-flutter-69e4168878e1)
you need to use [PageStorage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageStorage-class.html) to persit the state of the child you need after being destroyed.

here the example  retrieved  from the same page:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// ...

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

// ...

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<Widget> pages = <Widget>[
    ColorBoxPage(
      key: PageStorageKey('pageOne'),
    ),
    ColorBoxPage(
      key: PageStorageKey('pageTwo'),
    )
  ];
  int currentTab = 0;
  final PageStorageBucket _bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Persistence Example"),
      ),
      body: PageStorage(
        child: pages[currentTab],
        bucket: _bucket,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentTab,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            currentTab = index;
          });
        },
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'page 1',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            label: 'page2',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ColorBoxPage extends StatelessWidget {
  ColorBoxPage({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemExtent: 250.0,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Material(
          color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.cyan : Colors.deepOrange,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(index.toString()),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I will surely try this. My another question is does flutter re-recreate the children if the parent's state has changed? 
I thought it doesn't re-create if the WidgetTree is not changed.